# Is it acceptable "allowed by default, disallowed for specific data/actions"?

Tags: privacy, access-control

A friend told me that in the agile paradigm it is said that users are allowed by default to do anything but then they are blocked or disallowed to access or do certain identified actions. Just the contrary of minimum/least privilege.

That is a complete different paradigm where for a new application you identify what generic users cannot do and implement that security, not the contrary.

The result may be the same: everyone access what is allowed to access, but the implementation is completely different.

In which scenarios is this approach acceptable?
May it be secure?

Comment: The 'agile paradigm' usually refers to a 'project' management philosophy. Is your question, do you mean to refer to 'Agile software development' or something else?

Comment: Traditional companies are performing a transformation where security is needed but should change in order to be more agile. See for example "The Phoenix Project". In this environment with less unneeded burocracy it is recommended to use this approximation for managing privileges. I would like to know if people think it is a valid path or not from the POV of security.

Answer (score 3):

> That is a complete different paradigm where for a new application you
>   identify what generic users cannot do and implement that security, not
>   the contrary.

That sounds like an awful and insecure paradigm, too! What a huge design and development burden!

The secure paradigm is to block everyone from everything at the start, then add the privileges they need. This is called **Security** and **Privacy By Design and Default**.

If you do not know what the user needs to access when you are building something, then sure, you need to give the users access to everything and bar them from what you discover that you don't want them to have access to. Is this a secure method?

Um, no.

Over the past several years, developers have not been shown to be trustworthy in developing security with that paradigm. That's why [regulations](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/accountability-and-governance/data-protection-by-design-and-default/), [design frameworks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Security_by_Design_Principles), and [best practice](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3142459/security/nist-shifts-focus-of-security-guidance-to-engineering.html) says to not do that.

Could you end up with a secure result by bolting on restrictions after the fact? Sure. Could you do that consistently and reliably over time? History says 'no'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right but I would like to know more scientific reasons. Saying that "minimum privilege" is what we have done over the past several years sounds to me a falacy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition. Why is this unmaintenable? Why is insecure?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said that when developers retro-fit security, it tends not to end up secure. And your new questions in your comment are not what you asked in your question. How do you define "scientific reasons"?

Comment: With "scientific" I mean reasons that not sound like superstition like "it tends not to end up secure". Ok, it tends not to end up secure...but why? In my comment I'm not changing the question, I'm trying to highlight that don't see the root reason of why this approach is insure...

Comment: Quite simply: because you have to remember to think of it at some point in the future. And your iterative design process may have progressed to a point where making changes to the permissions is difficult or error-prone. This is an inherent (and self-evident?) risk in the entire agile programming paradigm just as with *any* design requirement in agile approaches.

Answer (score 1):

we should choose the least administrative effort solution for our needs, based on the risk that solutions represent.

Sometimes black list is a correct choice (what you call allow by default) as the if we had to do white list the universe would be too much and too big to control. That is why we define then what is critical risk and implement black lists. All rest falls in the acceptable risk.

Least privilege is easier in many situation where the user work is controlled and the universe of that he requires to do his job is restricted. Developers tend to require to test many things with multiple options so in those situations depending on what we need to defend black list might be more appropriate providing lowest possible impact on developer work.